# Orange 2.7 Install "UnsatisfiableError"

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, orange

I am trying to install Orange 2.7 using Anaconda2 on Windows and I am not having much luck.

I tried using: `conda install -c anaconda orange` in the command prompt.

This did not work and resulted in the following error prompt:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
-navigator-updater -> pyqt >=5.6 -> qt 5.6.0 -> icu 57.*
-orange -> pyqt 4.* -> qt >=4.8.6,<5.0
-orange -> pyqt 4.* -> sip >=4.16.4,<4.18
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Does anyone know how I can install Orange 2.7? Step-by-Step instructions would be very helpful!

I know this is the old version of Orange; however, my hands are tied and I MUST use Python 2.7 for this project.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if anyone else will care, but I figured this one out and wanted to share...

1. I went to the following site:
   http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
2. I downloaded the .whl file that I needed:

   Orange‑2.7.8‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl
3. Opened the command prompt, used pip install ".whl file location \ .whl file name"

That was easy! I hope this helps someone else as much as it has helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Orange 2.7 requires Qt4, while some applications in your conda environment (conda-navigator) require Qt5. As only one version of the Qt can be installed at the same time, this triggers an installation error.

Conflicting dependencies can be avoided by using a [separate environment](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) to install Orange 2.7.

To [create a new environment](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands) for orange, you need to run

```
conda create --name orange2 orange
```

Once the installation completes, you can [activate the new environment](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment) and run orange with the following commands:

```
activate orange2
orange-canvas
```

Answer (score 0):

The first solution did not work for me, I have'nt tried the second.
Here's what worked for me:

I had to downgrade pyqt.

```
conda info pyqt
```

With above command find the version of pyqt necessary. Mine was pyqt 4.11.3 compatible with python 2.7 on ubuntu.

Use the repo_url in the below command.

```
conda install <repo_url>
```

This will downgrade the pyqt and make it compatible with orange.

Try installing orange then. This worked for me.